# MongoDB Aggregate by fields exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to perform a sum with the following collection's schema:

```
{
    "_id" : "20160530/108107/31",
    "metadata" : {
        "date" : "2016-05-30",
        "offer" : "108107",
        "adv" : 31,
        "update" : ISODate("2016-05-30T15:27:20.240Z")
    },
    "daily_unique" : 4,
    "daily_gross" : 4,
    "hourly" : {
        "17" : {
            "unique" : 4,
            "gross" : 4
        }
    },
    "publisher" : {
        "738" : {
            "daily_unique" : 3,
            "daily_gross" : 3,
            "hourly" : {
                "17" : {
                    "unique" : 3,
                    "gross" : 3
                }
            }
        },
        "43" : {
            "daily_unique" : 1,
            "daily_gross" : 1,
            "hourly" : {
                "17" : {
                    "unique" : 1,
                    "gross" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "20160530/78220/59",
    "metadata" : {
        "date" : "2016-05-30",
        "offer" : "78220",
        "adv" : 59,
        "update" : ISODate("2016-05-30T15:24:49.900Z")
    },
    "daily_unique" : 2,
    "daily_gross" : 2,
    "hourly" : {
        "17" : {
            "unique" : 2,
            "gross" : 2)
        }
    },
    "publisher" : {
        "43" : {
            "daily_unique" : 2,
            "daily_gross" : 2,
            "hourly" : {
                "17" : {
                    "unique" : 2,
                    "gross" : 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First document have data from publisher 738 and 43, but second have data only from 43.
So, when I want to sum all data from publisher 738, I need to sum all daily_gross, or daily_unique only if its present in the publisher, as in the first document.

I am trying some different approaches, with $exists and $cond, but not getting results

```
aggregate(
    ['$match' => ['metadata.date' => date('Y-m-d')]],
    ['$group' => [
        '_id' => '$metadata.offer',
        'daily_u' => ['$sum' => '$daily_unique']
        ],
])
```

which gives me

```
[
    0 => [
        '_id' => '108107'
        'daily_u' => 4
    ]
    1 => [
        '_id' => '78220'
        'daily_u' => 2
    ]
]
```

When I try to dive deep in publisher I cannot get the results I want:

```
aggregate(
    ['$match' => ['metadata.date' => date('Y-m-d')]],
    ['$group' => [
        '_id' => '$metadata.offer',
        'daily_u' => [
            '$sum' => [
                '$cond' => [
                    'if' => [
                        'publisher.738' => ['$exists' => true],
                        'then' => 1,
                        'else' => 0
                    ]
                ]   
            ]
        ],
    ]]
)
```

But cannot get daily by publisher.
It even gets complicated when I try to get hourly data.
Can anybody point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: tbh it will be easier to aggregate if `publisher` will be an array of publishers data. With this structure you need to know all publisher names to deal with.

Comment: Thanks. I am updating every pub that connects when they connect, by the hour. So if a pub connect; I just add 1 to his document or subdocument. I am following MongoDB documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/  If you can provide a better structure and solution I will be more than grateful.